# How to crop an image into polygon shape in python

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a gui that helps me cropping faces and foldering them according to their moods such as angry, sad, happy, etc. My code looks like working fine but when I crop an image it saves the rest of image. I really don't know how can I accomplish that!!
My cropping fuctions:

```
    def on_mouse(self, event, x, y, buttons, user_param):
    # Mouse callback that gets called for every mouse event (i.e. moving, clicking, etc.)

    if self.done: # Nothing more to do
        return

    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        # We want to be able to draw the line-in-progress, so update current mouse position
        self.current = (x, y)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        # Left click means adding a point at current position to the list of points
        print("Adding point #%d with position(%d,%d)" % (len(self.points), x, y))
        self.points.append((x, y))
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        # Right click means we're done
        print("Completing polygon with %d points." % len(self.points))
        self.done = True


def run(self, image):
    # Let's create our working window and set a mouse callback to handle events
    cv2.namedWindow(self.window_name, flags=cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv2.imshow(self.window_name, image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    cv2.setMouseCallback(self.window_name, self.on_mouse)

    while(not self.done):
        # This is our drawing loop, we just continuously draw new images
        # and show them in the named window
        if (len(self.points) > 0):
            # Draw all the current polygon segments
            cv2.polylines(image, np.array([self.points]), False, FINAL_LINE_COLOR, 1)
            # And  also show what the current segment would look like
            cv2.line(image, self.points[-1], self.current, WORKING_LINE_COLOR)
        # Update the window
        cv2.imshow(self.window_name, image)
        # And wait 50ms before next iteration (this will pump window messages meanwhile)
        if cv2.waitKey(50) == 27: # ESC hit
            self.done = True

    # User finised entering the polygon points, so let's make the final drawing
    # of a filled polygon
    if (len(self.points) > 0):
        cv2.fillPoly(image, np.array([self.points]), FINAL_LINE_COLOR)
    # And show it
    cv2.imshow(self.window_name, image)
    # Waiting for the user to press any key
    cv2.waitKey()

    cv2.destroyWindow(self.window_name)
    return image
```

[I added the whole code here if you need](https://codepaste.net/rq3m3x)

Edit : When I changed this lines in open function:

```
fileName = unicode(fileName.toUtf8(), encoding="UTF-8")
img = cv2.imread(fileName)
```

To this:

```
im = Image.open(fileName).convert("RGBA")
imArray = numpy.asarray(im)
real_image = imageViewer.run(imArray)
```

It gaves me this errors:
Connected to pydev debugger (build 162.1967.10)
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/cgg/gui/template2.py", line 156, in open
    im = Image.open(fileName).convert("RGBA")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1956, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'read'

I get the file name with this code lines by the way

```
fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File",
            QtCore.QDir.currentPath())
if fileName:
   image = QtGui.QImage(fileName)
   if image.isNull():
      QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Image Viewer",
                    "Cannot load %s." % fileName)
            return
```

Comment: You can create a polygon mask and apply it to the image, like this answer explains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588074/polygon-crop-clip-using-python-pil

Comment: @ChristopherShroba thank you but I'm getting the picture's file name from a QtGui FileDialog object thats way i cannot use it like :
im = Image.open(fileName).convert("RGBA") 



It gives me an error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/cgg/gui/template2.py", line 156, in open
    im = Image.open(fileName).convert("RGBA")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1956, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'read'






Do you have any advice to fix that?

Comment: It seems like maybe your FileDialog is returning a QString object instead of just a normal string, and the image library is expecting a normal string, so I would guess that there's some way of converting it to a normal string.  If you're still having trouble, could you add the error to your question so it's more nicely formatted? And could you include the code that's generating the error?

Comment: In order to read in a QString object as python string, you can just use pythons `str()` method. In order to prevent something like this in general, you could try to use `import sip ` [`sip.setapi('QString', 2)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238193/pyqt-new-api-with-python-2) at the start of your script (before loading QT).